# Flutter and Unity integration apps are too big in size

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

I embedded a Unity 3D app inside a Flutter app using `flutter_unity_widget` package. Everything works fine, but now the problem is that the `apk` file generated by `flutter` is a very big size `(370mb)`. While I have only one 3D scene containing a single cube without script and a single page at flutter level. Please how can i downsize my apk?
Thanks for the good understanding.

[image][image]

Comment: That's a debug build? How large is a release build?

Comment: the large of release build is (284 mo). using the command : flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64